Is it natural to say "could he" instead of "if he could"? E.g.: "Could he have cast himself in the part of Mr Copthorne, he would not have attempted…"
I thought there were only three cases when we can use an inverted word order instead of "if":
If X should ... = Should X ...
If X were ... = Were X ...
If X had ... = Had X ...
But in the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language on page 970, I saw several more sentences:

(1) He does little himself. He only plans. But his agents are numerous and splendidly organised. Is there a crime to be done, a paper to be abstracted, we will say, a house to be
rifled, a man to be removed – the word is passed to the Professor, the matter is organised
and carried out.
(2) Dare a woman have a child, she’s putting her job at risk.
(3) Could he have cast himself in the part of Mr Copthorne, the villain and apostate, he
would not have attempted to run away from his captors.

Which of (1-3) are natural to you and which are not?

Based on the textbook, I drew the following conclusions:
"Is there" in (1) is archaic and sounds wrong nowadays. We must use only "If there is".
"Dare a woman" in (2) is archaic and sounds odd nowadays. We must use only "If a woman dare".
"Could he" in (3) isn't  archaic and sounds natural. We can use both it and "If he could".
Do you agree with these conclusions?
If not, then why not?

The excerpt from the textbook if need be:



Of these conditional constructions, where the modal or the auxiliary are fronted as in German, one of the ancestors of English,  one still in use involves the auxiliary:  Had we known you were coming to town, we would have met you at the airport. But sometimes the lexical verb  is fronted: "She's an old-fashioned ruler-on-knuckles sort of teacher. Get your declensions wrong, watch out!"

or "The tax department is unforgiving when income is hidden. Fail to declare income, and you're in hot water."

Conditional constructions (1) and (2) are antiquated, and are best avoided in speech and writing.
On the other hand, I believe (3) is possible, even though the form is very dated and may not be easily parsed. For example,
i) "Could they have left earlier, they would have."
In modern-day writing it would be:
   Had they been able to leave earlier, they would have.
   They would have left earlier if they could have.
ii) "Could she save money by staying home, she would."
In modern-day writing it would be:
   She would save money if she could stay home.
   If she could stay home, she would save money.

Curse me though he might, I'll beat him at cards this evening!

3 is certainly fine in writing, but I'd definitely expect "If he could" in speech.

None of 1-3 work.
The construction in (3) is only used for questions in unmarked English. You should not use such an inversion. "Could he" as an irrealis form would not be understood by a modern reader like me.

Someone who has read moderately widely (e.g. some 18th and 19th century novels) would understand such forms, but, as you say, most modern readers would just go 'Uh?'.

Yes,  I'd probably skim-read past it, if I were reading for pleasure.  But if I had to proofread this as modern writing, I'd mark it as a mistake.

I learned, to my cost, at school, that being 'bookish' in my essays could lead to being marked down or corrected by teachers who were, I surmised, inattentive or pressed for time. I still remember writing, at the age of 12, that the Swede Celsius was the deviser of the Centigrade temperature scale, and my English teacher put a red line through the word and wrote 'division' in the margin. He was clearly skimming. He did have the grace to apologise when I pointed it out.

@MichaelHarvey maybe the red line was for the spelling error… devisor?

@Mari-LouA - devisor is a legal term, one who devises property or money e.g. in a will, and a deviser is one who formulates in the mind, invents, contrives. (Longmans, but I used Collins in 1964).

My Lord, I would hate to ever enter into an argument with you. You'd remember every syllable uttered years later. Formidable memory, perhaps more of a curse than a gift, n'est-ce pas?

@Mari-LouA - I have very often been told that I have an unusually good memory; I always thought it was just average. It's not really a curse, because I am very good at recalling things if I want to remember them, and very poor indeed if I don't. It tends to be visual; I can recall the appearance of the essay I wrote, the blue ink I used, the red of the teacher's pen. Ever since I was small I have 'seen' words in my mind's eye (helps with spelling), usually in a Times Roman type font. I do not have an 'internal (speech) monologue' like, I gather, many people. Rather a slide show, I guess.

@Mari-LouA - last night I was telling my wife about an art book my parents bought me when I was 10 years old. I was greatly taken by the section on 'modern' art (it was 1962) and I particularly liked one picture, but try as I might, I couldn't remember the artist's name. I could 'see' the picture very clearly (blue, crudely done birds and a woman). No matter. We left it. I woke up in the night for a call of nature... Marc Chagall!! (the caption under the picture, that was absent before). Bear in mind I am now 72, and I think some decline is inevitable.

@MichaelHarvey  I wish private messaging was a thing on Stack Exchange but it's not, and we're veering off-topic. James is probably annoyed by all these pings. Sorry James! P.S I think the painting was the inspiration for the Italian classic 50s song better known as "Volare",  Nel blu, dipinto di blu

Would the Stack Exchange guidelines not discourage questions soliciting opinions, I'd reply that I personally find the second the least awkward of the three, principally because it does not initially look, to my contemporary eyes, like the beginning of a question, so there's less of the backtracking that needs to be done in the other cases, once I realize that they are not.

Hi sdenham. If you believe a question is off-topic you better flag it as such, as answering them only makes it harder to delete them or edit them to make them on-topic.

@Joachim I'm being a bit facetious here, and I have no objection to the question. My apologies if that has been misleading. Putting aside that first clause, the rest of my answer is a serious attempt to draw a somewhat objective distinction between the three sentences of the question.
